# Unable to read characters into a 2d matrix in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I have some characters in file that I have to read into a 2d array. I tried reading it using numpy.loadtxt but throws me value error.

```
   *  4  >  H  R  \  f  o  x
!  +  5  ?  I  S  ]  g  p  y
\  ,  6  @  J  T  ^  h  q  z
#  -  7  A  K  U  _  i  r  {
$  .  8  B  L  V  `  j  s  |
%  /  9  C  M  W  a  k  t  }
&  0  :  D  N  X  b  l  u  ~
'  1  ;  E  O  Y  c  m  v   
(  2  <  F  P  Z  d  n  w   
)  3  =  G  Q  [  e  \n
```

I have tried this so far

```
matrix = np.loadtxt("/Users/Downloads/ciphers-parameter-matrix/matrix.txt", dtype=str)
```

This is the error I get

> ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 2

This is the the text I have in a file. It is a 10*10 matrix. 
How?

Comment: @hpaulj have added the code and error.

Comment: See giving more information does help!  I though you were having `dtype` errors.  But it looks like you have problems with differing numbers of columns.  But that's not the full message is it?  Doesn't it give the number of columns?  Or is that a `genfromtxt` message?

Comment: `loadtxt` does not handle missing values.  `genfromtxt` is a bit better, but with this whitespace delimiter, it can't tell where columns are missing.  There's an alternative `delimiter` specification, a list of column widths.  You might have to use that here.

Comment: Getting characters from specific locations in the matrix helps in decrypting the message. And they are not missing values. They are left blank for intentional purpose.

Comment: But the blanks look just like the delimiter - a space.